# Replace semicolon delimiter in a Lookup column on the list view

Tags: javascript, list-view, lookup-column

When selecting multiple values, the data is separated with semicolons. When many values are selected it starts looking cluttered.

Is there any way to have each value on a new line?

For example, instead of:

```
Image1;Image2;Image3
```

I would like:

```
Image1
Image2
Image3
```

I'm using a lookup column inside a picture library. When looking at it within SPD it renders as a webpartpages:ListFormWebPart.

Is there any way of accomplishing this with Javascript?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar item come across my dest a few days ago. Using javascript and jquery. The code replaces the html coding of a semicolon with a html line break. It then copies the code and replaces the orginal code with it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ms-vb:contains(';')").each(function(){
    var htmlstr = $(this).html();
    var htmlmod = htmlstr.replace(/; <A/g,"</br><A");
    $(this).html(htmlmod);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this code really helped. One remark: I did have to lower the capitalization of the A tags: var htmlmod = htmlstr.replace(/; <a/gi,"</br><a");

Answer (score 1):

I think [Spservice](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) and [multiple choice filed values](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/5b916a71-e1ef-42a9-adee-9019ae863b20) will help you to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an [article](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2008/09/03/endusersharepointcom-taming-the-elusive-%e2%80%9ccalculated-column%e2%80%9d-customizing-a-contacts-list-part-ii-ii/) by Dessie Lunsford to create a calculated column to search and replace the semi colon with a space.  [This one](http://home.jordananderson.us/calculatedcolumntextsubstituation) might be helpful too.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't think a calculated column will help me in this instance. The calculated column will not let me select the lookup column I need to alter. 

The lookup column is a semicolon separated list of multiple images that belong to another picture library.

I was able to use javascript to replace the semicolon with a line break, but it breaks the links of the images.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as the OP and found @JBlountJr answer to work fine except on our users with IE11. This code was able to do the trick in all our browsers. Hopefully this helps someone.

Note: I modified the DispForm.aspx page and gave the  the lookup column an Id. 
Edit: Previous code actually did a few funky things to the URL's.

```
 $("#myId").contents().filter(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3){
        $(this).before('<br>'); 
        $(this).remove();
    }
 });
```

or

```
$("#myId").contents().filter(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3){ 
        $(this).replaceWith('<br>');
    }
});
```